# How secure is my encrypt method?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

So today I was doing what I sometimes do which is just program stuff for fun, and I decided to make my own encryption method. I think it's a basic stream cipher. The thing is I know next to nothing about cryptography, so I don't know how secure it is.

Here is the method **(implemented in PHP)**

```
public function encrypt($data)
{
    $keylen = sizeof($this->key);
    $i=0;
    $current = 0; //Current offset for the cipher
    $ascii = utf8_decode($data);
    $output = "";
    for ($i=0;$i<strlen($ascii);$i++)
    {
        //Moves the cipher offset based on the key and the value of what is being
        //encrypted
        $current += ord($ascii[$i]) + $this->key[$i % $keylen];
        $current = $current % 256;
        $output .= chr($this->cipher[$current]);
        //Moves the cipher offset to the value of the subsequent cipher key
        $current = $this->cipher[($current+1)%256];
    }
    return $output;
}
```

**Explanations**

`$this->cipher` a preshuffled array of all integer values from 0-255, each only showing once. (Effectively a one to one function, without any kind of pattern)

`$this->key` a 512 byte random key (Unlike the cipher array may contain repeated values)

The cipher and key used for decryption must be the same as the one used for encryption obviously to retrieve the plaintext.

**Decrypt method**

```
public function decrypt($data)
{
    $keylen = sizeof($this->key);
    $i=0;
    $offset = 0;
    $output = "";
    for ($i=0;$i<strlen($data);$i++)
    {
        $current = $this->r_cipher[ord($data[$i])];
        //Calculates the offset for the next iteration
        $next = $this->cipher[($current+1)%256];
        //Subtracts the calculated offset and key value
        $current -= $offset + $this->key[$i % $keylen];
        //Makes sure value is between 0 and 255
        $current = ($current+512)%256; 
        $output .= chr($current);
        $offset = $next;
    }
    return utf8_encode($output);
}
```

`r_cipher` is just the inverse function to the cipher function

http://pastebin.com/KbvHZnD1 Examples of the algorithm in use, gives the sample key and cipher as well as several examples

Comment: This should be an encryption method or a hash one?

Comment: It is not a hash method. The output will be the same size as the input

Comment: The biggest problem is, how are you going to transfer the cipher and the key to the person who wants to decrypt it?

Comment: @Shahbaz, isn't it the same for all symmetric cryptographic problems?Anyway I was hoping to use the code to encrypt data in my database, so giving myself the key and cipher shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: symmetric cryptographic algorithms*

Comment: While I guess that you'll get many responses of "don't reinvent the wheel", but if you get any luck with your question, it can be on http://cryptography.stackexchange.com and not here. That site is dedicated to cryptography and I believe your creation was developed by many people before and specialists might recognize it and comment on its strength.

Comment: Is this a reversible encryption, i.e. can you decrypt the results?

Comment: @zerm, yes I have decryption working

Comment: @AndrewDunn Would you be so kind to provide everything? It is already really painful to perform some cryptanalysis on this, and doing so just for fun. Don't make life even harder for people willing to help. Also, some test-vectors would be great (specify what output should be generated on predefined input).

Comment: @zerm no worries just a sec I'll upload some stuff for you :)

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp, they were no help, they don't do cryptanalysis apparently and closed my question :-/

Comment: BTW: This is quite close to RC4, but without proper keyscheduling

Comment: Is the `cypher` fields secret(i.e. part of the key)?

Comment: @zerm http://pastebin.com/KbvHZnD1

Comment: @CodeInChaos the key and cipher are secret

Comment: I closed this because we're not here to review home made crypto code and also the question would lend itself to extended discussion.

Comment: @Kev: Note that it was [also closed on crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/how-secure-is-my-encrypt-method), since they apparently don't want it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a streamy cypher, key reuse is probably very problematic.

---

```
$output .= chr($this->cipher[$current]);
$current = $this->cipher[($current+1)%256];
```

This implies that the state of `current` after this character is simply a permutation of the output byte.

So whenever one looks at two values that are a multiple of 512 bytes apart, have the same preceding output, and the input at that position is the same the output will be the same. That's a clear deviation from ideal cypher properties.

---

If you encode all 256 get the content of `cypher` apart from an offset on the index. After this you're reduced to a 512 byte caesar cypher.

Combining these two weaknesses you get a full key recovery on a known plain-text of a few hundred kB.

Comment: I know the question has been closed. But yeah I tested it with 20480 'a's and there was no repetition

Comment: It repeats approximately every 100MB

Comment: If you encrypt perhaps 1MB of data, and the attacker knows both the plaintext and the cyphertext he can most likely recover your key.

Comment: The answer is your crypto alogrithm is insecure, as @CodeInChaos points out knowing the `plaintext` and the `cyphertext` for a given record you can easily back calculate the key, given that this will be the same for all data saved you will then have access to the entire database. You have developed a 512 byte caesar cypher that rotates with each encoded character, this is not considered secure at all. Just use one of the many existing crypto algorithms instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

I dare to say, if `[you] know next to nothing about cryptography`, your invented encryption method is insecure by definition. It may stave off plain folks, but not someone who is a cryptography specialist or an experienced hacker.

Comment: That's why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Agree that this method is insecure. However, it will be interesting if someone can provide a concrete algorithm to break the encryption.

Comment: @miaout17: that's what cryptography specialists are for. Nonetheless, you not knowing a way to break the encryption doesn't mean the guy next door won't break it. Such a reasoning is like security by obscurity. Or security theater as Bruce Schneier puts it.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is a bit similar to the caesar cipher . you should have a look at the [Breaking the cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Breaking_the_cipher) section of the Wikipedia page on Caesar cipher

Comment: That's my first thought. However, it is different from Caesar cipher because the mapping is rotating. Do statistic on byte frequency will discover nothing.

Comment: Actually, it's much more like a [Vigenere Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) with an [S-Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box). As such, I'd expect it to have the same weaknesses of a Vigenere cipher.

Answer (score 1):

vIts quite tough to say how secure is an encryption algorithm. I guess there are some standard programs like [CMVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMVP) to validate an algorithm.

The algorithm must be open to some hacking forum, if any, and has to proove its strength there.